# Error restoring database in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, database-restore

I have taken a backup of database using pgAdmin of a postgresql DB.
I am trying to restore it on to an another system using

> D:\OB_dependencies\DB_Backup>psql -U postgres OpenBravo <
>   OBPOS_DB_BACKUP_23MAY_2013

Some of the tables are created, but script stops with a error

```
ERROR:  literal carriage return found in data
HINT:  Use "\r" to represent carriage return.
CONTEXT:  COPY ad_session_usage_audit, line 2355
```

Please suggest me a solutions for this issue. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From postgreSQL mailing list it is stated that:

> I'd only expect this if an old pg_dumpall was being used

It occurs, when dealing with a version so old that the behavior of COPY itself
was different.

One possible workaround is to use the ***--inserts*** option of pg_dump. That will mean slower dump and restore, though.

refer [**`here`**](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/FA20D4C4FEBFD148B1C0CB09913825FC01EBE7D0CF@XCH-SW-06V.sw.nos.boeing.com) .

Also worth referring [here](http://forums.devshed.com/postgresql-help-21/restoring-data-from-pg-7-1-3-7-4-release-99865.html).

Comment: `--inserts` saved me when trying to restore a dump from 9.6 on 9.5. Thanks so much!