# How can I get a plain text postgres database dump on heroku?

Tags: sql, postgresql, heroku

Due to version incompatibilities of my postgres database on heroku (9.1) and my local installation (8.4) I need a plain text sql database dump file so I can put a copy of my production data on my local testing environment.

It seems on heroku I can't make a dump using pg_dump but can instead only do this:

```
$ heroku pgbackups:capture
$ curl -o my_dump_file.dump `heroku pgbackups:url`
```

...and this gives me the "custom database dump format" and not "plain text format" so I am not able to do this:

```
$ psql -d my_local_database -f my_dump_file.sql
```

Answer (score 80, accepted):

You could just make your own pg_dump directly from your Heroku database.

First, get your postgres string using `heroku config:get DATABASE_URL`.

Look for the Heroku Postgres url (example: `HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_RED_URL: postgres://user3123:passkja83kd8@ec2-117-21-174-214.compute-1.amazonaws.com:6212/db982398`), which format is `postgres://<username>:<password>@<host_name>:<port>/<dbname>`.

Next, run this on your command line:

```
pg_dump --host=<host_name> --port=<port> --username=<username> --password --dbname=<dbname> > output.sql
```

The terminal will ask for your password then run it and dump it into output.sql.

Then import it:

```
psql -d my_local_database -f output.sql
```

Comment: Another way:
1) `heroku pgbackups:capture`
2) copy this to the clipboard: `heroku pgbackups:url`
3) `curl -o latest.dump <paste pgbackups:url here>`

Comment: The limitation of `heroku pgbackups` is that it will not run without user auth, even on Heroku within the app. It seems that pg_dump will run with only the DB auth.

Comment: heroku config:get gave me error "Missing argument: KEY", but just heroku config gave that URL info

Comment: @Alex Does the Postgres url go into the `<host_name>`? Or does part of it go into the `<port>`? I.e. what do we do with `postgres://user3123...2938`?

Comment: Update: the format of the url string is: `scheme://username:password@host:port/database`

Comment: @Robert The string format is `postgres://<username>:<password>@<host_name>:<port>/<dbname>`. To translate the example I gave into pg_dump, it would be `pg_dump --host=ec2-117-21-174-214.compute-1.amazonaws.com --port=6212 --username=user3123 --password --dbname=db982398`. Edit -- Yep, you got it!

Comment: @Alex i am having run this command 
pg_dump --host=ec2-54-225-103-167.compute-1.amazonaws.com --port=5432 --username=kelmrouuyipqym --34e96181c91451adbf073c1482c02a067afe6bf8f919d2919465410f4f63072b --dbname=de0pfea769s8q1 > output.sql
it gives me error like
pg_dump: unrecognized option '--34e96181c91451adbf073c1482c02a067afe6bf8f919d2919465410f4f63072b'

Answer (score 37):

Assuming you have a `DATABASE_URL` configured in your environment, there is a far simpler method:

```
heroku run 'pg_dump $DATABASE_URL' > my_database.sql
```

This will run `pg_dump` in your container and pipe the contents to a local file, `my_database.sql`. **The single quotes are important.** If you use double quotes (or no quotes at all), `DATABASE_URL` will be evaluated locally rather than in your container.

If your whole purpose is to load the contents into a local database anyways, you might as well pipe it straight there:

```
createdb myapp_devel  # start with an empty database
heroku run 'pg_dump -xO $DATABASE_URL' | psql myapp_devel
```

The addition of `-xO` avoids dumping `GRANT`, `REVOKE`, and `ALTER OWNER` statements, which probably don't apply to your local database server. If any of your `COPY` commands fail with the error `ERROR:  literal carriage return found in data` (mine did), see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16712868/166053).

It's quite possible this didn't work two and a half years ago when this question was originally asked, but for those looking for a way to easily get a dump of your Heroku Postgres database, this appears to be the simplest possible way to do this today.

Comment: I would like to double upvote, since the answer solved all my problems including carriage returns. However, I would like to preprocess the original dump (without `--inserts`) to gain better performance on restore. Any ideas?

Comment: This was extremely useful to me. Thank you!

Comment: This is the only correct answer for incompatible PostgreSQL versions locally vs. remote, which is what the OP wanted. For local Windows environments, remember to use double quotes around the command: `heroku run "pg_dump $DATABASE_URL" --app yourapp > db.sql`

Answer (score 32):

Heroku's PGBackups [actually uses pg_dump behind the scenes](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-import-export), and the "custom format" is actually [pg_dump's custom format (`-Fc` parameter)](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/app-pgdump.html), not Heroku's own custom format.

This means you can use `pg_restore`, which is part of Postgres, to restore your Heroku backup into another database directly:

```
pg_restore -d mydatabase my_dump_file.dump
```

In addition, [if you call `pg_restore` without specifying a database to restore to, it'll print SQL statements to standard out](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/app-pgrestore.html), so you can turn your Heroku backup into a SQL file that way:

```
pg_restore my_dump_file.dump > sql_statements.sql
```

UPDATE: on more recent versions of postgres, the following command is required (thanks to comment from PatKilg)

```
pg_restore latest.dump -f - > sql_statements.sql
```

Comment: This answer should be the correct one. Using `pg_restore my_dump_file.dump` will give you plain text sql statements. Thanks Adam!

Comment: the second part of this answer saved my ass!

Comment: pg_restore: error: one of -d/--dbname and -f/--file must be specified

Comment: `#!/bin/bash`  
`HEROKU_APP_NAME=app-name`  
`OUTPUT_SQL_FILENAME=~/Downloads/myDB.psql`  
`heroku pg:backups:capture --app $HEROKU_APP_NAME`  
`heroku pg:backups:download --app $HEROKU_APP_NAME`  
`pg_restore ./latest.dump -f $OUTPUT_SQL_FILENAME`  
@timbophillips

Comment: The correct command to generate sql now is `pg_restore my_dump_file.dump -f - > sql_statements.sql`

Answer (score 9):

for people like me that stumble into this problem in 2020:

```
heroku pg:backups:capture -a app-name
heroku pg:backups:download -a app-name
```

the tool will actually tell what command to use after the capture. To get SQL from your `latest.dump` file:

```
pg_restore -f sqldump.sql latest.dump
```

and that's it.

Answer (score 1):

`pg_dump` accepts a connection string so you don't need to deconstruct it manually like mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22896985/3163631.

Let's say your connection string looks like this (I randomized the username and pass and added fillers for the remaining. The "shape" of the connection string is correct):

```
postgres://Nb6n8BTA4rPK5m:DzEPtwZUkJfgbMSdYFUbqupvJeEekihiJNzqGXa3wN2pmYRGcLQ8Sa69ujGn2RSkb@ec2-00-000-000-000.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/j4aaaaaaaaaam1
```

Even though it is in the `postgres://<username>:<password>@<host_name>:<port>/<dbname>` format, you can use it directly like so:

```
pg_dump postgres://Nb6n8BTA4rPK5m:DzEPtwZUkJfgbMSdYFUbqupvJeEekihiJNzqGXa3wN2pmYRGcLQ8Sa69ujGn2RSkb@ec2-00-000-000-000.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/j4aaaaaaaaaam1 > output.sql
```

Maybe this was not possible with `pg_dump` at the time Alex(https://stackoverflow.com/users/3457661/alex) answered in 2014.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what worked for me:

```sh
heroku pg:backups:capture
heroku pg:backups:download
pg_restore latest.dump -f latest.sql
psql -f 'latest.sql' -d '<DEV_DB_NAME>'
```

Explanation:

1. First we create a snapshot of the database on Heroku
2. Then we download the snapshot as 'latest.dump' (the name can be changed using `-o '<name>.dump'`)
3. Convert the binary dump into plain SQL, which can be imported without raising "pg_dump: error: aborting because of server version mismatch"
4. Import the file into the local database

Of course, if your running version of postgresql is compatible with Heroku's, `heroku pg:pull DATABASE_URL <DEV_DB_NAME>` is simpler to type and remember.

Comment: Is there a way to use INSERT instead of COPY?

Comment: @siniradam `pg_dump` accepts the `--inserts` option, so change the 3rd line to `pg_restore latest.dump -f latest.sql --inserts`. The [`pg_dump` documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgdump.html) says: _This will make restoration very slow. Any error during restoring will cause only rows that are part of the problematic INSERT to be lost, rather than the entire table contents. Note that the restore might fail altogether if you have rearranged column order, use the `--column-inserts` option in that case, though it will be even slower._

Answer (score 0):

```
Heroku pg:backups:capture
Heroku pg:backups:download
```

Taken from https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-import-export.
Now you have a binary file. To obtain the file in plain text format, the following worked for me. Note: You will need to install PostgreSQL.

```
pg_restore latest.dump > latest.sql
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just download the Heroku dump file and convert it into plain text format.

In newer versions, directly redirecting the output of `pg_restore` to an SQL file won't work. Doing so will produce an error:

```
pg_restore my_dump_file.dump > my_dump_file.sql
pg_restore: error: one of -d/--dbname and -f/--file must be specified
```

Instead, to output the result in plain text format, `-f` should be used:

```
pg_restore my_dump_file.dump -f my_dump_file.sql
```

This will convert the heroku "custom database dump format" to "plain text format".

Then import this file:

```
psql -d my_local_database -f my_dump_file.sql
```