# Postgres copy Heroku Production DB to local development DB

Tags: database, postgresql, heroku

I have a heroku database, `d76mj7ltuqs`.

I then have a local database, `test_development`.

The schema is the same on both of these databases - I want to pull all of the data from my production database and overwrite my local database, so that local is an exact replica of production at the time of pull.

How can I do that in Postgres?

Comment: Maybe [`pg_dump`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-pgdump.html) and [`pg_restore`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-pgrestore.html) ?

Answer (score 82):

Use heroku's "pg:pull":

You'll need to clear your local DB:

```
rake db:drop
```

Then collect some information from Heroku:

```
heroku pg:pull DATABASE_URL test_development
```

This will connect to the heroku DB, and copy it to the local database.

See [Heroku's documentation on pg:pull](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#pg-pull) for more details.

Comment: Not sure if this is a new thing now, but when defining an app you need to put in `--app` before the app name.

Comment: Same here. I need: `heroku pg:pull DATABASE_URL database_local_name --app myapp`

Comment: First, I thought I need to replace DATABASE_URL with my heroku config corresponding value, but not.

Answer (score 11):

This command should do the work:

```
heroku pg:pull DATABASE_URL database-name --app heroku-app-name
```

Comment: Surprised this isn't getting more support.

Answer (score 7):

clean your local database:

```
rake db:schema:load
```

dump your heroku database:

```
heroku pg:backups:capture -r <**your production git repo name**>
heroku pg:backups:download -r <**your production git repo name**>
```

load data in your local database

```
pg_restore --verbose --clean --no-acl --no-owner -h localhost -d <**test database name**> latest.dump
```

Answer (score 3):

this is how i do it, be sure to gzip it as your database grows. also don't export the ACL as you likely don't have the same postgres user on heroku and local accounts. replace  with your specific details.

```
 pg_dump -h ec2-##-##-##-##.compute-1.amazonaws.com -p <port> -Fc --no-acl --no-owner -o -U <username> <databasename> | gzip > dumpfile.gz
 #<Prompt for Password>
 gunzip -c dumpfile.gz | pg_restore --verbose --clean --no-acl --no-owner -d test_development -U <local_username>
```

Comment: The `pg_dump` can compress the dump without external `gzip`. Look at the `--compress=0..9` option.

Answer (score 1):

Use your terminal to make a local `pg_dump` and then either `psql` or `pg_restore` it into your local database.

Similar method can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22887524/how-can-i-get-a-plain-text-postgres-database-dump-on-heroku/22896985#22896985).

Answer (score 0):

If this is a Rails app, you can use the following script to overwrite your local database with the latest dump you've generated on Heroku. If you uncomment the line with `heroku pg:backups capture`, the script will generate a new snapshot on Heroku before downloading it to your machine.

Note that you shouldn't have to edit the script, since it reads all the configuration from your database.yml file.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require_relative '../config/environment'

# Uncomment the line below if you want to generate a new snapshot of the
# Heroku production database before downloading it to the local machine
# `heroku pg:backups capture`

database_dump_file_pathname = Tempfile.new('latest.dump').path
`heroku pg:backups:download --output #{database_dump_file_pathname}`

# Get database config fom database.yml file
database_config = YAML::load_file(Rails.root.join('config', 'database.yml'))
database_name = database_config['development']['database']
database_username = database_config['development']['username']
database_password = database_config['development']['password']

# Overwrite local database with dump
cmd_line_arguments = [
  '--verbose',
  '--clean',
  '--no-acl',
  '--no-owner',
  '--host localhost',
  "-U #{database_username}",
  "-d #{database_name}",
  database_dump_file_pathname
].join(' ')
`PGPASSWORD=#{database_password} pg_restore #{cmd_line_arguments}`
```

See the [Heroku docs on downloading DB backups](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-backups#downloading-your-backups) for details.