# Putting local Postregsql database in Heroku

Tags: django, heroku, heroku-postgres

I am creating a Django app on Heroku. While I am testing it locally, finally I am checking by uploading everything to heroku and seeing if it works for real on the remote server as well

To quickstart, I went to the admin panel and created a bunch of data to run the view functions on. When I am pushing the source code to heroku via git (git push heroku master), I also want to push up the database from local to heroku, so that I dont need to enter it again on the server side

How do I achieve this?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

Grab your the postgres string from your Heroku database using `heroku config:get`

Look for the Heroku Postgres url (example: `HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_RED_URL: postgres://user3123:passkja83kd8@ec2-117-21-174-214.compute-1.amazonaws.com:6212/db982398`).

Next, run this on your command line:

`pg_dump --host=<host_name> --port=<port> --username=<username> --password --dbname=<dbname> > output.sql`
The terminal will ask for your password then run it and dump it into output.sql.

Then import it:

`psql -d <heroku postgres string> -f output.sql`

Note: in each place where you see `<.....>` in the above code, be sure to substitute your specific information. Thus you would put your `username` where it says `<username>`, and your heroku database url where it says `<heroku postgres string>`.

Similar answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22887524/how-can-i-get-a-plain-text-postgres-database-dump-on-heroku/22896985#22896985).