# How to get database schema from Heroku PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, heroku, schema

I need to assess the database schema of the Postgres instance running on Heroku. Without luck, I have tried the following methods:

```
heroku run -a my_app_name 'pg_dump -s DATABASE_URL' > output.sql
```

where DATABASE_URL would be the whole string out of

```
heroku config:get DATABASE_URL -a my_app_name
```

This is the closest I could get, as the command runs but the output is left empty. For this I added the flag *-s* for *pg_dump* to only get the schema and no data.

I have also tried following this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22887524/how-can-i-get-a-plain-text-postgres-database-dump-on-heroku) but couldn't use it to get the schema.

Comment: Your first `heroku run -a ...` one should work fine, worked for me just now. Are you sure you're using the right `DATABASE_URL`?

Comment: Thanks @muistooshort, you are right, I eventually got the output file, successful as it ends with *-- PostgreSQL database dump complete* . However, I am not sure how long it took, the command execution never ends and I have to close the terminal window once done because not responding. Anyway good.

Comment: Your answer was the only thing that worked for me after hours of trying...
In my case I copied `DATABASE_URL` from the heroku -> my app -> resources -> view database credentials then copied `URI` if that helps anybody else.

Answer (score 0):

If you need permission to access the app, you can run it.

```
heroku pg:pull DATABASE_URL local_db_name --exclude-table-data="*.*" --app heroku_app_name
```

It will pull all the tables' structures but no data.